Problem with Notion Formula Field Not Returning Full Value
I'm using Make.com to automate tasks and interact with my Notion database, but I’ve hit a wall with a formula field in Notion that isn’t returning the full result as expected. The formula I’ve set up is supposed to pull email addresses from multiple related databases. Here’s the formula for reference:
((prop("Teams").map(current.prop("Email")).concat(map(prop("Project 1"), current.prop("PM").map(current.prop("Email")))).concat(map(prop("Project 2"), current.prop("PM").map(current.prop("Email")))).concat(map(prop("Project 3"), current.prop("PM").map(current.prop("Email")))))).flat().unique()

The issue: when Make retrieves the page data, it only returns one email address instead of the full list. I’ve ensured that all databases are shared correctly. I also tried pulling the data directly via the Notion API, but had no luck there either – it still only returns a single email address.
Has anyone encountered this issue with formula fields in Notion not returning full results through Make or the API? Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.
I set up a formula in Notion to compile email addresses from multiple related databases (Teams, Project 1, Project 2, Project 3). The formula was supposed to concatenate and flatten these email lists into one unique list. I expected this to produce a full list of emails when retrieving page data through Make.com.
To troubleshoot, I double-checked that all related databases were shared with both the Make integration and the Notion API, ensuring permissions were correctly set up. Additionally, I tried a direct API request outside of Make to rule out any issues specific to Make’s integration.
Despite these efforts, the result is still incomplete: Make and the API request both return only a single email instead of the full list. I also tested parts of the formula individually, and each seems to work as expected on its own, but the full formula still produces partial results.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
